# Spark Sql Flatten Json

Tags: json, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON which looks like this

```
{"name":"Michael", "cities":["palo alto", "menlo park"], "schools":[{"sname":"stanford", "year":2010}, {"sname":"berkeley","year":2012}]}
```

I want to store output in a csv file like this:

```
Michael,{"sname":"stanford", "year":2010} 

Michael,{"sname":"berkeley", "year":2012}
```

I have tried the following:

```
val people = sqlContext.read.json("people.json")
val flattened = people.select($"name", explode($"schools").as("schools_flat"))
```

The above code does not give schools_flat as a json.
Any ides on how to get the expected output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify schema explicitly to read the json file in the desired way.
In this case it would be like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

case class json_schema_class(  cities: String,  name : String, schools: Array[String])
var json_schema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[json_schema_class].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]

var people = sqlContext.read.schema( json_schema ).json("people.json")
var flattened = people.select($"name", explode($"schools").as("schools_flat"))
```

The 'flattened' dataframe is like this:

```
+-------+--------------------+
|   name|        schools_flat|
+-------+--------------------+
|Michael|{"sname":"stanfor...|
|Michael|{"sname":"berkele...|
+-------+--------------------+
```